# Longest prefix match queries in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, match, prefix

What is the most efficient combination of schema and query to do a longest matching IP prefix search in Cassandra? That is, given an IP prefix, find the row with the longest matching IP prefix. An IP prefix is composed of an IP address and a prefix length. For example: Assume I have the following table:

```
IP Address   Prefix Length     Other Fields
1.0.0.0         8                 A
1.2.0.0         16                B
1.2.3.0         24                C
1.2.3.4         32                D
```

The row with the longest matching prefix for 1.2.3.5/32 would be (1.2.3.0, 24, C).

The prefix length can be any number between 0 and 32, not just multiples of 8.

Comment: You need to use Solr with cassandra.  "like" queries not possible with cassandra.

Comment: Newer versions of Cassandra support like queries with SASI indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SASI indexes for like queries, but you need to implement the level  logic (going from 4 segments prefix to 3 and so on).

Link to SASI indexes example:
http://rustyrazorblade.com/2016/02/cassandra-secondary-index-preview-1/